# get text of label that belongs to checked radio button

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the `text` of the labels that belong to `checked` radio buttons, but don't seem quite to be able to.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").on("click", "#btn", function(){

    var radios = $("input[type='radio']");

    $.each(radios, function(index, element){
      if ($(this).prop("checked") === true){

        var radioID = element.id;
        $("label").each(function(ind, elm){

          if ($(elm).prop("for") == radioID){
            console.log($(elm)); 
          }

        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uniwum/2/edit)

For whatever reason that just prints out

> > > --
> > >       [11:07:13.834] ({0:({}), context:({}), length:1}) @ http://jsbin.com/uniwum/2/edit:71

in the console. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Do this way:-

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function() {
        var idVal = $(this).attr("id");
        alert($("label[for='"+idVal+"']").text());
    });
});
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/EmpWV/)**

### UPDATED:

Below are documentation references:-

- **[Category: Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**
- **[Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**

Comment: that's cool. Where is the documentation on what exactly you can put in those brackets in a jquery selector? `input[type='text']` `label[for='something'` etc? Seems really handy. Thank you!

Comment: thank you for the documentation. I think this is a great solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('table input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
        console.log($(this).parent().next().find('label').text());
        }
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rQX7H/)**

Update: Since they're radio buttons, an even faster method is:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    console.log( $('table input[type="radio"]:checked').parent().next().find('label').text() );
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rQX7H/1/)**

Comment: In your method it looks like you just forgot the call to `.text()`. E.g. `$(elm).text()`

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just was trying to get the element itself to print to the log before I did `text()`. I just wondered why it only printed `[11:07:13.834] ({0:({}), context:({}), length:1})` as opposed to showing a jquery object.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("input[type='radio']:checked").parent().text()
```

Comment: If you have multiples radio buttons. This answer get the value not only for the selected radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `.text()` function to get the text of the element once you've selected it, like this: `$(elm).text()`.

In this case, since `elm` is a DOM node already, you can call plain `elm.innerHTML` for the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$("td",$(":checked").parent().parent()).text()
```

Link for jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rQX7H/2/

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain what is happening with that comma in the selector?

Comment: select td , says look in $(":checked").parent().parent() which gives the entire row and get the td text

Comment: I see. I don't know how I feel about stringing together `parent().parent()`. Seems like that sort of thing is sort of messy. Thank you though.

Comment: @j08691  Updated the code same as user2084375 with some twist and turns

Answer (score 0):

You can do this is in many ways depending on the HTML written for the radio button and the text for the radio button, I am sighting 2 of the ways which can be done with very less efforts.

***Method 1***:
        Assign custom data-attributes to the radio button with the same text which is to be displayed.

```
    <input id="radio4" name="radios1" type="radio" value="4" data-value="radio 4" /> radio 4
    <input id="radio5" name="radios1" type="radio" value="4" data-value="radio 5"/> radio 5
    <input id="radio6" name="radios1" type="radio" value="4" data-value="radio 6"/> radio 6
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Get from data-value" />
```

For details on Custom Data Attributes, visit : [Custom Data-* Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

Script for getting the text :

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn", function () {
            var value = $("input[name=radios1]:checked").attr("data-value");
            alert(value);
        });
```

***Method 2***:
        Convert the html for the radio buttons so as to assign a same [name] property for all of them, then place "label" fields for the radio buttons as below

```
<input id="radio1" name="radios" type="radio"/>
        <label for="radio1"> radio 1</label>
    <input id="radio2" name="radios" type="radio"/>
        <label for="radio2"> radio 2</label>
    <input id="radio3" name="radios" type="radio"/>
        <label for="radio3"> radio 3</label>
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Get from Label" />
```

Script for getting the text :

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn1", function () {
        var idVal = $('input[name=radios]:checked').attr("id");
        $("label[for='"+idVal+"']").text();
        //If you have the radio button in HTML table structure write it as below
        $('input[name=radios]:checked').parent().find('label').text();
    }
```

Hope this helps :)