# Get selected radio button on selected in function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup:

```
    <div class="secondary-filter" onclick="searchByFilter()">
        <ul class="secondary-filter__list">
            <li class="secondary-filter__list-item">
                <input type="radio" id="secondaryFilter-all" name="secondaryFilter" value="All">
                <label for="secondaryFilter-all">All</label>
            </li>

            <li class="secondary-filter__list-item">
                <input type="radio" id="secondaryFilter-marked" name="secondaryFilter" value="Marked">
                <label for="secondaryFilter-quoted">Marked</label>
            </li>

            <li class="secondary-filter__list-item">
                <input type="radio" id="secondaryFilter-pending" name="secondaryFilter" value="Pending">
                <label for="secondaryFilter-unquoted">Pending</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

How can I obtained the label of the checked radio button in the following function?

```
function searchByFilter() {
    var x = $("input[name='secondaryFilter']").find('input:checked');

    console.log(x.val());
}
```

I'm trying this.. but it's not working. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get text of label that belongs to checked radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141530/get-text-of-label-that-belongs-to-checked-radio-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$("input[name='secondaryFilter']")` creates a jQuery object if `<input>` elements, but `.find` only searches through *descendants* - the input elements don't have any descendants, rather you want to get the matching `<input>` in the current collection.

You should also attach the event listener using Javascript rather than in an HTML attribute. By listening for `change` events, you'll have events that only fire when one of the inputs change, rather than when anywhere in the container is clicked.

Also, probably best to have the `label` next to each input have its `for` attribute match the `id` of the input - that way, when clicking the label, the input will be checked - eg, change

```
<input type="radio" id="secondaryFilter-marked" name="secondaryFilter" value="Marked">
<label for="secondaryFilter-quoted">Marked</label>
```

to

```
<input type="radio" id="secondaryFilter-marked" name="secondaryFilter" value="Marked">
<label for="secondaryFilter-marked">Marked</label>
                            ^^^^^^
```

While you could use `.filter` instead, to find the element in the current jQuery object matching the condition:

```js
$("input[name='secondaryFilter']").on('change', function() {
  var x = $("input[name='secondaryFilter']").filter('input:checked');
  console.log(x.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="secondary-filter">
  <ul class="secondary-filter__list">
    <li class="secondary-filter__list-item">
      <input type="radio" id="secondaryFilter-all" name="secondaryFilter" value="All">
      <label for="secondaryFilter-all">All</label>
    </li>

    <li class="secondary-filter__list-item">
      <input type="radio" id="secondaryFilter-marked" name="secondaryFilter" value="Marked">
      <label for="secondaryFilter-marked">Marked</label>
    </li>

    <li class="secondary-filter__list-item">
      <input type="radio" id="secondaryFilter-pending" name="secondaryFilter" value="Pending">
      <label for="secondaryFilter-pending">Pending</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It would be easier to just put the `:checked` into the first selector string:

```
const checkedInput = $("input[name='secondaryFilter']:checked");
```

```js
$("input[name='secondaryFilter']").on('change', function() {
  var x = $("input[name='secondaryFilter']:checked");
  console.log(x.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="secondary-filter">
  <ul class="secondary-filter__list">
    <li class="secondary-filter__list-item">
      <input type="radio" id="secondaryFilter-all" name="secondaryFilter" value="All">
      <label for="secondaryFilter-all">All</label>
    </li>

    <li class="secondary-filter__list-item">
      <input type="radio" id="secondaryFilter-marked" name="secondaryFilter" value="Marked">
      <label for="secondaryFilter-marked">Marked</label>
    </li>

    <li class="secondary-filter__list-item">
      <input type="radio" id="secondaryFilter-pending" name="secondaryFilter" value="Pending">
      <label for="secondaryFilter-pending">Pending</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this work attach a `change` event handler directly to the `radio` elements. Then you can get `$(this).val()` from it when the event occurs. You can also use `next().text()` to get the value shown in the `label`, although given that the radio value and innerText of the label are the same, this seems a little redundant.

Also note that the `for` attributes of the `label` elements need to match the `id` of the targeted `radio`, so I've fixed the HTML there too.

```js
$('.secondary-filter :radio').on('change', function() {
  var $radio = $(this);
  var $label = $radio.next();
  console.log(`value: ${$radio.val()}, label: ${$label.text()}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="secondary-filter">
  <ul class="secondary-filter__list">
    <li class="secondary-filter__list-item">
      <input type="radio" id="secondaryFilter-all" name="secondaryFilter" value="All">
      <label for="secondaryFilter-all">All</label>
    </li>

    <li class="secondary-filter__list-item">
      <input type="radio" id="secondaryFilter-marked" name="secondaryFilter" value="Marked">
      <label for="secondaryFilter-marked">Marked</label>
    </li>

    <li class="secondary-filter__list-item">
      <input type="radio" id="secondaryFilter-pending" name="secondaryFilter" value="Pending">
      <label for="secondaryFilter-pending">Pending</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
input[name='secondaryFilter']:checked" ,'.secondary-filter'
```

It will check for checked radio button inside the class of the div

```js
function searchByFilter() {
    var x = $("input[name='secondaryFilter']:checked" ,'.secondary-filter')
   console.log(x.val())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="secondary-filter" onclick="searchByFilter()">
        <ul class="secondary-filter__list">
            <li class="secondary-filter__list-item">
                <input type="radio" id="secondaryFilter-all" name="secondaryFilter" value="All">
                <label for="secondaryFilter-all">All</label>
            </li>

            <li class="secondary-filter__list-item">
                <input type="radio" id="secondaryFilter-marked" name="secondaryFilter" value="Marked">
                <label for="secondaryFilter-quoted">Marked</label>
            </li>

            <li class="secondary-filter__list-item">
                <input type="radio" id="secondaryFilter-pending" name="secondaryFilter" value="Pending">
                <label for="secondaryFilter-unquoted">Pending</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

var x = $('input[name=secondaryFilter]:checked').val()